# NHibernate IList or List?

Tags: nhibernate, ilist

I've looked around Stackoverflow and seen a couple questions related to NHibernate IList vs List. I have a question of my own...

Since the purpose of IList is to have a lazyloaded list, what purpose does it serve returning from a repository. After all if you ToList() your repository call, you are creating a definitive object? So therefore regardless if your method is returning an IList or a List, there is no more lazy loading involved, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your repository returns an IQueryable, the results will be retrieved first time you enumerate it. If you call ToList() on it, it will retrieve the results at this moment, because ToList will enumerate the IQueryable.

Now, lazy loading is not necessarily impacted by this behavior : suppose you have Customers and Orders. 
Each customer has a property named CustomerOrders, which is marked as lazy loaded. That means that when you load your list of customers, the orders are retrieved only if you try to enumerate the CustomerOrders property for each Customer.
So if you just do a ToList() on your GetCustomers() method's return value, it has no effect on the lazy loading of CustomerOrders

Comment: Thanks, this isn't what I was sure about, but it certainly sounds right. So it is probably always best to get into the habit of returning an IList from a repository method regardless?

Comment: @MattB For laziness, you'll be returning `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`, for materialized, `IList` makes sense for lots of reasons. There is no particular reason to even involve `List<T>` (except if you use `'ToList()` at the end of a LINQ sequence, but even in that case, you'll likely want to return `IList<T>` for consistency and let the result be implicitly upcasted) (And yes I realize you probably know all this now but this answer is very prone to misinterpretation as-is, hence my answer...)

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much correct, but are confusing some concepts so I'll take it from the top.

You are correct that `.ToList()` `materializes` things.

`IList` is just an abstract interface for a materialized list.

NHibernate requires `IList` in some cases [because it proxies things](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html). When using `session.QueryOver` etc., you'll use the `List()` extension method to return an `IList` (which is materialized) or `Future()` to return an `IEnumerable` (lazy). 
The `QueryOver` is pretty stable and complete and well paved.

On the Linq provider side, you use `session.Query`, and you can either stay at the `IQueryable` level to have a 'spec of a query', `IEnumerable` for lazy or `IList` for materialized items. Normally you'll use `ToList()` to materialize, and `AsEnumerable()` (or a cast / type conversion) to get to `IEnumerable`. NB I cannot make the statement I made re QueryOver about the LINQ provider.